# How can I show a superscript character in .NET GUI labels?

Tags: c#, string

Is it possible to Build a string or fix the label in the GUI so that I get square meter information to the user. So that the output will look like 21 m2 but the 2 is raised.

Regards

Comment: I don't know about .NET, but Java Swing controls can accept HTML to be rendered. If .NET supports that, you could write "21 m<sup>2</sup>".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the "²" caracter :
 21 m²

The unicode code point is U+00B2 and the UTF-8 hexadecimal is c2 b2

Answer (score 1):

Use a font that has the ² character.

Eg MS Sans Serif : 0xB2

Answer (score 1):

In the label, use the HTML character reference "`&sup2;`" for the superscript in m².