# Displaying Math in a label

Tags: c#, winforms, math

I'm coding a UI in C# for a particular discrete math problem (not important what) and I'd like to be able to output a proper fraction, and letters with subscripts (and superscripts) to a label. For example:

```
(a_1 x a_2 x ... x a_n)^6
_________________________
            n
```

But nicely, and with actual super and subscripts. I'm familiar with LaTeX.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: you can use this one http://www.forkosh.com/mimetex.html

Comment: I this you are looking for this questions.

[Go to this link and check here you will find your answer hopefully.][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042334/how-to-add-superscript-power-operators-in-c-sharp-winforms

Comment: @Mansh Thanks, this helps for superscripting. Any ideas on the fractions?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using `RichTextBox`control. Check the [SelectionCharOffset property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectioncharoffset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to make the selection `subscript` and `superscript`. You can also use this property to position fractions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Well you can go to their and check.

[Goto this URL which explain to you about fraction](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ed4a2911-0d27-4f2a-b97f-dbff626a4e19/display-a-proper-fraction-in-text-box-with-c?forum=winforms)

Comment: Yeah I saw that but I didn't find the answer particularly helpful. After following your link, I did some more research and am currently testing a solution. If it works I will post back with what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So you can also try this [Fraction example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9078/Fraction-class-in-C) i think this will working example