# Adjusting Unicode based on user input

Tags: c#, winforms, unicode

I'd like to display `e^x = answer` in a label on a Windows Form, but using the appropriate superscript rather than `^x`.

`x` is the user's input from a text box, answer is `Math.Exp(x)`. All of the variables are declared and the calculations are done after the user clicks the `e^x` button (it's a simple calculator application).

Unicode for superscript 4-9 is `\u2074` to `\u2079`. I just realized superscript 2 and 3 follow a different pattern, but I'll worry about that later

I've been trying various ways to concatenate `\\u207` and my `x` variable but the result displayed on my label is either `\u207x` or `System.Char[]`

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to accomplish? Or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: Im guessing youll need this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not work with standard label. Refer to this question how to do it using `HtmlRenderer`

[How to add superscript power operators in c# winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042334/how-to-add-superscript-power-operators-in-c-sharp-winforms)