# How to display exponent in a label?

Tags: c#, winforms, exponent

I'm looking for a possibility to write a label text for cubic meters where the 3 is written as an exponent to m. For example:

```
mylabel.Text="m3";
```

Is it possible to write the 3 as an exponent?
How should I do it?

Comment: https://unicode-table.com/en/00B3/ --> `m³`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add superscript power operators in c# winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042334/how-to-add-superscript-power-operators-in-c-sharp-winforms)

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
mylabel.Text = "m" + "\u00B3";
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to escape your Unicode characters in strings as C# is inherently Unicode. Just put your Unicode characters as they are into the string. For example:

```
mylabel.Text = "m³";
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a *exact* or *proper* way of doing this. But one way you can do this is by entering the digit that you want to be a exponent into this website
https://lingojam.com/SuperscriptGenerator.

And then copy the converted version. So for your example I put a 3 in there, and the converted version I got was ³. Then you just connect it together.

`m³`

Now you can just add it to the label...

```
mylabel.Text="m³";
```

Comment: Super it works perfectly